# Ruby/Rails How to create link from one view to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby/rails and have been learning by creating a simple application. I have a simple view where I want to add a button which when clicked will take you to another view. I tried adding controller and configure the routes but still not sure how to proceed.

The project structure looks like

```
app
  controller
    health
    report
  view
    health
      index
    reports
      index
```

I created a new controller called reports and in my routes.rb I added

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'reports/index'    
end
```

There are two things I want to do. Add a button in health/index file which  when click will view reports/index. How to do this ?

Comment: You should really start with something like https://www.railstutorial.org rather than asking a bunch of questions that are better answered by a book or tutorial. Basically you´re not really grasping the MVC concept. You don't link to views - you link to routes that are handled by your controllers. Your controllers then render a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with max about reading up on MVC and doing the Rails Tutorial. But to answer your question...

In your `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'reports#index'
  get 'health#index'
end
```

Then, in your `health/index.html.erb` file:

`<%= link_to 'Reports Index', reports_path %>`

This will create a link that, when clicked on, will go to the Reports Index page.